# How to create a custom metric in TfLearn or TensorFlow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tflearn, metric

TensorFlow offers many common evaluation metrics, but I don't know how to create my own metric. 
I'm building a CNN model based on AlexNet for grasp detection and I want to use the rectangle metric when evaluating the data (like in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.3128.pdf). Rectangle metric means both of the following conditions are satisfied:

```
- The grasp angle is within 30 degree of the ground truth grasp.
- The Jaccard index of the predicted grasp and the ground truth is greater than 25 percent.
```

So my first try is to use the model of AlexNet which is available on TFLearn (https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/alexnet.py) and create a file for calculating the metric with numpy. Below is the metric file which includes incomplete code (because I'm not allowed to share), but it has the main parts as following:

```
def grasp_error(grasps,targets,max_angle = 30,min_overlap=0.25):
        return np.mean([np.max([grasp_classification(grasps[i],targets,max_angle,min_overlap) for i in range(grasps.shape[0])])]) #for target in targets[i]])

#compute the error of the test set
def grasp_classification(grasp,target,max_angle = 30,min_overlap = 0.25):
    ...
    if abs(np.arctan2(grasp[sinpos],grasp[cospos]) - np.arctan2(target[sinpos],target[cospos]))< (max_angle * 2./180.)*np.pi:
        if jaccard_index(grasp,target) > min_overlap:
            return 1
    return 0

# computes Jaccard index of two grasping rectangeles
def jaccard_index(grasp,target):
    ...
    return intersect/overall
```

I have tried adding this to the metrics.py file in Tflearn folder:

```
class Rectangle(Metric):
def __init__(self, name="Rechtangle"):
    super(Rectangle, self).__init__(name)
    self.tensor = None

def build(self, predictions, targets, inputs=None):
    with tf.name_scope('Rechtangle'): # <--------- name scope
         with tf.Session() as sess:
              #tf.InteractiveSession()
              prediction = predictions.eval()
              target = targets.eval()
              self.tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(grasp_error(prediction, target, max_angle = 30,min_overlap=0.25))
    self.built = True
    self.tensor.m_name = self.name
    return self.tensor
```

And then using this in the end of the AlexNet:

```
rect_metric = tflearn.metrics.Rectangle()
network = regression(network, metric=rect_metric, optimizer='momentum',
                     loss='mean_square',
                     learning_rate=0.0005)
```

And I got this error:

```
 File "gnet.py", line 57, in <module>
    learning_rate=0.0005)   
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/layers/estimator.py", line 159, in regression
    metric.build(incoming, placeholder, inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/metrics.py", line 119, in build
    prediction = predictions.eval()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 569, in eval
    return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3741, in _eval_using_default_session
    return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 982, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value is_training
     [[Node: is_training/read = Identity[T=DT_BOOL, _class=["loc:@is_training"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](is_training)]]
```

There's is a problem with implementing the sess.eval() in the metrics file but it's the only way to turn a tensor to numpy array, isn't it? Please let me know if you have any ideas to fix this. Thank you very much!

EDIT: I tried another way, as recommended here: `https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/207` and implementing this in the code:

```
def rect_metric(prediction, target, inputs):
    x = []
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    with sess as default:
        pred = prediction.eval(session=sess)
        tar =  target.eval(session=sess)
        x = tf.reduce_sum(grasp_error(pred,tar))
    return x
```

Now the error does not show up but the training stops with this exception:

```
Reminder: Custom metric function arguments must be defined as: custom_metric(y_pred, y_true, x).
```